# change css class for mobile

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have the following code on a wordpress site

```
<article class="post-featured post-grid overlay overlay-ratio overlay-ratio-vertical parallax-video post-6792 post type-post status-publish format-video has-post-thumbnail hentry category-tech post_format-post-format-video post-visible" style="background-image: url(http://http://theoldcontinent.mgtestsite.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/Schermafbeelding-2017-07-10-om-18.54.13-530x300.jpg);" data-video="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GnfNta6SosA">
::before
 <span class="overlay-label"><i class="icon icon-ribbon"></i></span>
  <div class="overlay-container"></div>
  <a href="http://theoldcontinent.mgtestsite.com/watch-the-1961-chevrolet-corvette-the-definition-of-cool/" class="overlay-link"></a>
</article>
```

I need to remove these classes for mobile `overlay overlay-ratio overlay-ratio-vertical parallax-video`. I would like to use jQuery or CSS. I would like the code to simply read like the below, so the layout is different for mobile:

```
<article class="post-grid post-6800 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-last-night-in-sweden post-visible">
```

Which selector do I need to use?  I tried this, but nothing happens:

```
$('article').removeClass("post-grid.overlay.overlay-ratio.overlay-ratio-vertical.parallax-video");
```

How would I remove style and data-video. And all of this only for mobile? Max-width:600px

Comment: you have a missing `.` at the first class in the `removeClass()`

Comment: You need to replace `.` to space `' '` Should be `$('article').removeClass("post-grid overlay overlay-ratio overlay-ratio-vertical parallax-video");`

Comment: $('article').removeClass("post-grid overlay overlay-ratio overlay-ratio-vertical parallax-video"); Not sure how effective this will be, need to look at your html/css. Because this might spoil the entire styles of 'article' tag!!!

Comment: this is many class so you can use separate removeClass which help you better cause there is space and other thing

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/removeclass separate each class by a single space, and don't include the `.` prefix. I would also strongly suggest you use CSS media queries for this, instead of hacking around the classes in the UI using JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this option which remove class

Final answer :

```
 var window_weight = $(window).width();
    if (window_weight <= 600) {
        $('article').removeClass('post-grid overlay overlay-ratio overlay-ratio-vertical parallax-video');

    }
```

also check this

```
if (/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
            || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(navigator.userAgent.substr(0, 4))) {

        $('article').removeClass('post-grid overlay overlay-ratio overlay-ratio-vertical parallax-video');
    }
```

**Option 1**
Use exact class name and also add space in every class name

```
$('article').removeClass('post-grid overlay overlay-ratio overlay-ratio-vertical parallax-video');
```

**Option 2**

You can use multiple removeClass like this

```
$("article").removeClass("post-grid").removeClass("overlay ").removeClass("overlay-ratio") ...;
```

Comment: how do I remove it only for mobile say max-width 600px?

Comment: @LTech i am not sure which you want, you want to remove this class when max-width 600px or something else?

Comment: yes, I only want to remove the class for mobile. when the max screen width is 600px.

Comment: only 600 or 600 or less both?

Comment: check my update answer which max width 600 or less then remove it

Answer (score 1):

i think it should be like this

```
$('article').removeClass("post-grid overlay overlay-ratio overlay-ratio-vertical parallax-video");
```

change "." with "[space]"

Answer (score 1):

Use Modernizr (https://modernizr.com/docs)

**Modernizr.mq allows for you to programmatically check if the current browser window state matches a media query.**

Use this in your custom script

```
if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 600px)')) {
  //Code goes here 
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to work. Is it supported in every browser? I'm using chrome

Comment: did you add the Modernizr script? It should work in every browser.

Answer (score 0):

Use javascript for checking device

```
 if( /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) {
     // add code for removing classes here
    }
```